# What is the best stats to compare the lists of proportions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have proportions of cells from two samples (A and B) that overexpress certain genes.

```
        dataset A  dataset B
   gene1  x1          y1
   gene2  x2          y2
   gene3  x3          y3
    ...   ...         ...
   geneN  xn          yn
```

According to my hypothesis, dataset A should have more cells that overexpress all N genes than dataset B. What is the best way to assess the difference between these two datasets?

Comment: Do you have access to the counts used to find the proportions? Are you looking for evidence that for each gene type in Dataset A the proportion is higher than in dataset B? Can you clarify what exactly you're looking to prove? There are differences between testing for differences in proportions vs counts, and differences overall vs by gene

Comment: I do have counts for genes' expression. If I want to compare expression based on counts, I will have to integrate and scale the counts from 2 datasets and use Wilcoxon rank sum test. Here, I wonder if there is another way where I can compare two unrelated datasets. I need to prove that dataset A has a higher proportion of cells where all N genes (or the majority of them) are expressed.

Answer (score 0):

As @jros suggests in Comments, you need to use counts instead of proportions.

Suppose you have $n = 500$ samples of Gene 1, with $x_1 = 43, y_1 = 30,$ and you and you want to test $H_0: p_1 \ge p_2$ against $H_1:p_1 < p_2.$ Then one method is to use `prop.test` in R to show that $H_0$ is rejected, as follows:

```
prop.test(c(53, 30), c(500,500), cor=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(53, 30) out of c(500, 500)
X-squared = 6.9504, df = 1, p-value = 0.00838
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.01192097 0.08007903
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
 0.106  0.060
```

There are several variants of this test. Here we use
parameter `cor=F` to avoid continuity correction for
relatively large $n$s. Look at links under 'Related' in the margin for other variants.

*Note:* **Proportions without counts are not useful
for inference.** With about the same proportions
based on half as many counts, there is not a significant difference at the 5% level:

```
prop.test(c(26, 15), c(500,500), cor=F)$p.val
[1] 0.0793877
```